# Far future expiration date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, yslow, google-pagespeed

How can i mention far future expiration date for google ad services, google analytics...

These are some things shown in gtmetrix site for yslow.

i am using nginx server

http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js

http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js

http://storage.googleapis.com/code.snapengage.com/js/cb502944-bd87-448a-b7e3-34353b0136c7.js

https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/code.snapengage.com/btn/livechat_right_en.png

how can i add future expiration date for these links.

Comment: You can't. These links not served from your servers, so you can't control them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the Cache expiration date, the answer as Alexey Ten is "you can't".

Those resources are not controlled by you, nor on your servers. They are loaded by the browsers from external servers, therefore you have no control over them. The expiration header is set by the server that serves the asset.

In some cases you can proxy the resource (aka put a custom layer between the resource and the client), so that you can configure the cache via the proxy. But I'm not sure in this case it's a recommendable option.

Comment: Thank you got a complete picture of it.